# Mathematics to compare points

Tags: graphing-functions

I am not sure if this a question for the mathematics stackoverflow or some other. If it is then please move it.

Basically, I have a programming challenge where given list of points (which form a line or a curve), I need to determine a point is on left or right of these list of points.

Does anyone knows a mathematical answer to this question or does this needs to be moved to another place?

P

Edit: The point that needs to be compare may not be on the line

Comment: Look at the smallest and largest x values of the points on the list if they are given in (x,y) form.

Comment: How do you interpret a list of points which forms a curve ? Do you assume the "curve" is a series of straight line segments ? What if the "curve" is not monotonic, e.g. a parabola: you may have a given point "inside" which is both on the left and the right of the curve ?

Answer (score 1):

I would have to think a little longer about how to determine which side of a general *curve* some point lies, but with the line it is very straightforward.

The following approach *only* holds if the given set of points is entirely co-linear. Pick any two distinct points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$, then line $f(x)$ will have be $f(x) = \left( \dfrac{y_2- y_1}{x_2 - x_1}\right)(x-x_1) + y_1$ where the fraction is the slope. Once you have the line, consider the point $(x_3,y_3)$ which you are to determine if it is on the left or right of $f(x)$.

Find the value of $a = f(x_3)$. If $a > y_3$, your point is "below" $f(x)$ which I would interpret as to the right of $f(x)$ if you were riding the line $f(x)$ from the negative $x$-axis to the positive $x$-axis.

If $a = y_3$, your point is on the line.

If $a < y_3$, your point is "above" $f(x)$ and I would consider it to be to the left of $f(x)$ for the same reasons mentioned in the twice-previous paragraph.

The only exception, as hinted with finding distinct points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$, is when $x_1 = x_2$. If the points given to you are co-linear but they all posses the same $x$-value, this means you have a line of the form $x = c$ which has no defined slope (among other properties). But this would be the easiest case because then you just compare your $(x_3,y_3)$'s first coordinate with the value of $c$ and you can find which side of $x=c$ it lies on.

This reminds me of [Project Euler's Problem 102](https://projecteuler.net/problem=102). I would consider using an implementation of the notion of a cross product for a more general case involving some arbitrary curve. Just a guess at an approach: isolate the two nearest points to your mystery point. Take vector 1 to be the line segment connecting the 2 points, and take vector 2 to be the line connecting the first given point and your mystery point. Analyzing the sign of the [cross(vector) product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) involving those points (assuming you adhere to some convention like the [Right-Hand-Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule)) will tell you which side of the curve your mystery lies on. [Disclaimer: I haven't tried this yet but it's an approach worth considering/revising/improving]